# What is better to use in DotNet RGB24 or RGB32 for performance

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, image, image-processing

I am using a lot of images in my application (also for animation). Because a 3 Megapixel image, 2048 × 1536 = 3,145,728 holds about 9MB of Data (each Pixel = R+G+B), I ever tought it is more performant to work with instead of 32BIT=12MB (each Pixel = A+R+G+B). But the architecture of graphic cards seems to be optimized for RGB32 because tranceparancy is used a lot in games.

Can you explain what is more recommended?
Is there any difference while working in DotNet with Framework or WPF?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It probably makes little difference because 24bpp in memory storage uses 4 bytes per pixel for alignment reasons. Algorithms can ignore the alpha channel which will be a smidgen more efficient but in terms of storage there's no difference.