# Performance update - Better image framerate in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, image, image-processing

I am working in WPF in .Net 4.0. I have some huge images from camera 1392x1040 pixels. Every frame comes as `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and will be converted into a BitmapImage by using

```
Public Function BitmapToWpfBitmapSource(ByVal bmSrc As System.Drawing.Bitmap) As BitmapSource
                    If bmSrc Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
                    Dim res As BitmapSource
                    Dim Ptr As IntPtr
                    Ptr = bmSrc.GetHbitmap(System.Drawing.Color.Black) 'Create GDI bitmap object
                    res = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(Ptr, IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(bmSrc.Width, bmSrc.Height))
                    Dim ret As Integer = DeleteObject(Ptr) 'Delete GDI bitmap object
                    GC.Collect() 'Because the code is not managed, we need to call the collector manually to avoid memory spikes
                    Return res
End Function
```

If I update the images in GUI I can get about 7 frames / second.

[image: image framerate count]

There were some possibilities to increase speed by decreasing quality:

- Render with Nearest neighbor

`RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(Me.ucWindow1.VideoPresenter1.img1, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor)`

- Work with threads to update every frame

  Dim dl As New SetImageDelegate(AddressOf UpdateImageInGuiGuiThread)
  Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(dl, imgSrc)
- Tested with 32Bit and 24Bit images -
  [compare Imageformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198816/what-is-better-to-use-in-dotnet-rgb24-or-rgb32-for-performance)

Using [Performance profiling suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) for framerate count

But CPU is still about 10% and not 100% and framerate is about 12FPS maximum instead of 39 (Winforms).

How to improve framerates from camera?

Comment: that GC.Collect looks slow -- try finding a way to call this not-every-frame.

Comment: The reason for it being there looks incorrect. The comment says it needs to be called because the code is unmanaged but GC.Collect will only free managed objects from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CPU is 10% then something besides the processing of your image is happening. I suspect the answer to your question is something that you have not mentioned here. eg reading from disk or reading from camera.

Comment: But camera serves his 21FPS as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: My point was that something besides processing the image is taking place. I would start by commenting out all the code in the function, does the function get called 21 times per second? If so then the problem is inside the function, if not then it is somewhere else. If it's inside the function then you need to work out what is causing the CPU to go idle. As  MattS423 said, the GC.Collect() could be an issue, possibly it is a blocking call. In 10 years I've never used GC.Collect except in testing and I have done a lot of unmanaged stuff including video streaming.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your GPU load is high. When I have done similar programs, the WPF rendering uses a lot of GPU resources and this can easily be a bottleneck.